# Lagrange Multipliers restriction equation problem

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

There's a straight line going from B to C in the first quadrant of x,y coordinate system.

B is $(0,s)$, C is $(t,0)$

Let A $(3,3)$ be a point  on the line going from A to B.

Find the equation of the line so the distance between B and C will be minimal.

Well, I've started by finding points that their squared distance is minimal \ maximal (Helps me getting rid of un-needed roots) so the distance between B and C is $f(x)=x^2+y^2$.

Now i wanna find a restrict equation and use Lagrange multipliers. But i can't find a proper one.

Guidelines please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance between $B$ and $C$ is $\sqrt{s^2 + t^2}$ so you need to minimize $f(s,t) = s^2 + t^2$.  The fact that $A$ lies on the segment connecting $B$ and $C$ gives you a constraint: compare slopes to get $\dfrac{3-s}{3} = \dfrac{3}{3-t}$, which is equivalent to $st - 3s - 3t = 0$. Let $g(s,t) = st - 3s - 3t$ and minimize $f(s,t)$ on the level set $g(s,t) = 0$.

Comment: Awesome, Many thanks.

Comment: -1. Isn't the obvious minimum of $s^2+t^2$ subject to $st-3s-3t=0$ occurring at $(0,0)$, which is nonsense for this problem?

Comment: Of course. This is why you look for all critical points and find the minimum that is relevant to the problem.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I will upvote the answer if you edit it -- my vote is locked in...